# Vulnerabilities when installing axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, axios

I've just started learning node and react from a course on Udemy (course was uploaded last year - 2020). I understand that the code that the tutor is using may be outdated by the time I'm trying to do the same thing, but I have not received any vulnerabilities installing anything except while trying to install axios. I have installed npm globally, created a react app (create-react-app) and have used express, all of which work properly. Is there something I'm missing while installing axios?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.15.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ axios@0.23.0
updated 1 package and audited 1911 packages in 10.84s

153 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details        

found 27 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 18 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

It said try running `npm audit fix`, but when I did this, it said I have to fix these manually. Axios does exist in my *package.json* though.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

These are only the dependencies. Do I need to fix these vulnerabilities, or will my program just continue to function normally?

Comment: Axios 0.23 is fine. If you're using create-react-app, you will have warnings and issues with npm audit. Here is an article by the head of React at Facebook, responsible for create-react-app, that explains why: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

Comment: So I don't need to worry about anything breaking? I'm only concerned because I was doing a course like this a year ago (a react native course), and when one component failed I had no idea what to do.

Comment: I'd recommend ignoring these warnings and focusing on your coursework. The warnings are only a problem if you are planning to release to production, and even then they're case by case.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're seeing aren't from axios, they're from `npm audit` reporting errors from create-react-app, particularly the react-scripts package. If you're using create-react-app for coursework, these errors will not impact your project, as they are related to security, not functionality.

If you plan to release this project to production, I recommend evaluating the errors considering the following:

- How secure does my project need to be? Am I writing data coming in from the internet?
- Is this an error with a developer tool like jest, or in a part of the application like express?
- If high security is required with strong validation tools, is it time to move off create-react-app?

The current status of `npm audit` is controversial among developers. It is a valuable free security scan, but more sophisticated tools like `snyk` and other paid tools are often used in larger companies.